# Mongoid: multiple checks on a single field

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I need to select transactions with the same type as a given transaction. And I need to check that it doesn't return all transactions with the nil type.

With ActiveRecord I can easily write:

```
given_transaction = Transaction.first
needed_transactions = Transaction.where('type != nil and type = ?', given_transaction.type)
```

and all works

when I try to write the same thing with mongoid:

```
needed_transactions = Transaction.where(:type => given_transaction.type, :type.ne => nil)
```

It generates the following query:

```
"query"=>{:type=>{"$ne"=>"planned"}}
```

In other words, mongoid ignores the first check and only uses the last check on the field.

I tried "all_of", "all_in", "and" — and still can't find the working solution.

Maybe I am doing something wrong... My world is going upside down because of this... :(((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying.html):

> All queries in Mongoid are Criteria, which is a chainable and lazily evaluated wrapper to a MongoDB dynamic query.

And looking at [the Criteria docs for `where`](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#where) we see a bunch of examples with a single condition. But remember the *chainability* mentioned above. Perhaps you're looking for this:

```
needed_transactions = Transaction.where(:type => given_transaction.type).where(:type.ne => nil)
```

The [`Criteria#and`](http://mongoid.org/docs/querying/criteria.html#and) docs might make good reading as well:

> Adds another simple expression that must match in order to return results. This is the same as `Criteria#where` and is mostly here for syntactic sugar.
>
> ```
> MONGOID
> # Match all people with last name Jordan and first name starting with d.
> Person.where(last_name: "Jordan").and(first_name: /^d/i)
>
> MONGODB QUERY SELECTOR
> { "last_name" : "Jordan", "first_name" : /^d/i }
> ```

I have to admit that I don't understand why you're checking `:type` twice like that though; if `given_transaction.type.nil?` is possible then you could deal with that without even querying your database.

And BTW, with ActiveRecord you'd want to say this:

```
Transaction.where('type is not null and type = ?', given_transaction.type)
```

As far as the strange query you're getting is concerned, when you do this:

```
Transaction.where(:type => given_transaction.type, :type.ne => nil)
```

Mongoid ends up trying to build a Hash with two values for the `:type` key:

```
{ :type => 'planned' }
{ :type => { :$ne => nil } }
```

and somehow it ends up replacing the `nil` with `'planned'`. I don't know the internal details of Mongoid's `where` or the methods it patches into Symbol, I'm just backtracking from the observed behavior.

Comment: `Transaction.where(:type => 'bla', :type.ne => nil)` leads to an error `'NoMethodError: undefined method merge! for "bla":String'`.

Comment: `hm:local >> Transaction.where(:type => 'bla').and(:type.ne => nil)[7777]`
makes this query:
`MONGODB hm2_development['transactions'].find({:type=>{"$ne"=>nil}})`

Comment: I know, this query is strange and I have already rewritten it. It's just a totally unexpected behaviour for me.

Comment: @Ildar: I don't know if Mongoid supports `where(:a => b, :c => d)` style queries, I use MongoMapper. The Hash problem I noted at the end might be the real source of the problem. You might need to manually build an `:$and` query. But fixed is fixed :)